# How to deserialize dateTimeV2 entites from LUIS V3 prediction endpoint json

Tags: json, azure, c#-4.0, azure-cognitive-services

Is there a way to deserialize the LUIS V3 prediction endpoint JSON containing different types of entities like builtin entities, list entities and pattern entities using c#.Net? I am facing major issue while deserializing and extracting the data and values from **builtin.dateTimeV2 entities**.

Please find the MS reference links below: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-migration-api-v3

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-prebuilt-datetimev2?tabs=1-1%2C2-2%2C3-1%2C4-1%2C5-2%2C6-1#date-range-resolution-examples-for-day-of-week

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-get-started-get-intent-from-rest?pivots=programming-language-csharp

**Is there a possible way in .Net to extract all the type, timex, resolution values etc. of dateTimeV2 entities and intents from v3 prediction endpoint json.**

Please find the Json samples (especially the builtin.dateTimeV2) below:

Json1:

"entities":{"datetimeV2":[{"type":"date","values":[{"timex":"2020-11-23","resolution":[{"value":"2020-11-23"}]}]}],"$instance":{"datetimeV2":[{"type":"builtin.datetimeV2.date","text":"tomorrow","startIndex":19,"length":8,"modelTypeId":2,"modelType":"Prebuilt Entity Extractor","recognitionSources":["model"]}]}

Json2:

"entities":{"datetimeV2":[{"type":"datetime","values":[{"timex":"2020-11-23T09","resolution":[{"value":"2020-11-23 09:00:00"}]}]}],"$instance":{"datetimeV2":[{"type":"builtin.datetimeV2.datetime","text":"tomorrow morning 9am","startIndex":19,"length":20,"modelTypeId":2,"modelType":"Prebuilt Entity Extractor","recognitionSources":["model"]}]}

Json3:

"datetimeV2":[{"type":"daterange","values":[{"timex":"XXXX-06","resolution":[{"start":"2020-06-01","end":"2020-07-01"},{"start":"2021-06-01","end":"2021-07-01"}]}]}],"$instance":{"datetimeV2":[{"type":"builtin.datetimeV2.daterange","text":"june","startIndex":20,"length":4,"modelTypeId":2,"modelType":"Prebuilt Entity Extractor","recognitionSources":["model"]}]

Json4:

"entities":{"datetimeV2":[{"type":"daterange","values":[{"timex":"2020","mod":"end","resolution":[{"start":"2020-07-01","end":"2021-01-01"}]}]}],"$instance":{"datetimeV2":[{"type":"builtin.datetimeV2.daterange","text":"end of year","startIndex":0,"length":11,"modelTypeId":2,"modelType":"Prebuilt Entity Extractor","recognitionSources":["model"]}],

Comment: Is there any update on this as to how to get the dateTimeV2 entity data like type, timex, resolution values like "start", "end" and "value"?

Comment: Is there any update on the above ask? Please let me know how to deserialize the dateTimeV2 entity for LUIS v3 prediction endpoint